# Simplify grpc calls on thin golang api with protobuf

Tags: optimization, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am currently playing around with grpc on golang and trying to figure out the best way to make an extensible 'thin' api that i can use to pass all requests to their relevant services.

I currently have the structure of:

- Service 1

  - routes.go
  - rpc.go
- Service 2

  - routes.go
  - rpc.go

Within the routes files, it creates a new routeGroup that i then register in main, then each handler for a route parses any params etc into a protobuf request and calls a function within RPC:

```
func showFeed(c *gin.Context) {
    message, err := RpcFeedGet(&social.ShowRequest{LocationId: 1})

    resp := http.HttpResponse{c, "feed", err, message} 
    http.ParseResponse(&resp) //Checks if there is an error and handles response headers etc.
}
```

Now within rpc im currently defining the below for each service which seems to be really inefficient to me as there is a lot of code reuse, how would i optimize/reduce the code reuse within this method

```
func connect() (*grpc.ClientConn, pb.Service1Client) {

    //Consul is being used for discovery, this just gets the address to dial
    consul := discovery.Init()
    service, err := consul.Lookup("service1", "")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to get service definition: %w", err)
    }

    //Dial the connection to the service
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(service.Address(), grpc.WithInsecure())

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to client service: %v", err)
    }

    //Creates the service client (service1) and returns it
    client := pb.NewService1Client(conn)

    return conn, client
}

func RpcFeedGet(data *pb.ShowRequest) (string, error) {
    conn, client := connect()
    defer conn.Close()

    //This line calls the protobuf GetFeed rpc service
    resp, err := client.GetFeed(context.Background(), data)

    return rpcHelp.CheckResponse(resp, err) //Handles any errors returned
}
```

Is there a way i can pass a function to a sub function that calls the connect/defer within the Rpc function and also normalise the `connect()` method so i dont have to redeclare it for each service? bearing in mind it returns a different client on each instance?